# Infimum of norm of Span of a closed subspace $Y$ and $x \notin Y$ is larger than zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

Let $Y $ be a proper closed subspace of a normed space $X$.

Let $z \in X\setminus Y$.

Then

$ \inf \{\| z + y \| \space  | \space y\in Y \}>0.$

Is this proposition true?

Comment: $d (x,Y)=0\iff x\in \overline Y $.

Comment: This is true. But what does it have to do with my proposition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If
$$
\inf_{y\in Y}\|z+y\|=0,
$$
then there would exist a sequence $\{y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset Y$, such that
$$
\|z+y_n\|\to 0,
$$
or equivalently, $y_n\to -z$, which would mean that $-z$ lies in $\overline{Y}$ the closure of $Y$. But $Y$ is closed, and hence $\overline{Y}=Y$. Hence $-z\in Y$ and thus $z\in Y$, since $Y$ is a subspace. Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

In a metric space for each subset , $d(x,Y)=0$ if and only if $x\in \overline{Y}$. So, being $Y$ a closed set, it contains each of its accumulation points. So, being the distance non-negative by definition and in this case different from $0$, you have the thesis.

Answer (score 0):

$  \{\| z + y \| \space  | \space y\in Y \} = \{d(z,-y) \space  | \space y\in Y \} =  \{d(z,y) \space  | \space y\in Y \} $

Since $Y$ is closed and $z\notin Y$, $z$ is not a limit point of $Y$. Therefore $z$ is constantly bounded away from $Y$ by $\delta>0$.